# Не соединяется на порт 8889 через локалку

Tags: lan, php, websocket, port

Проблема: не соединяется по вебсокету ноут с компом. Порт 8889. Через локалхост все соединяется. Через локалку хоть убей, не хочет. В фаерволе входящее соединение вообще не отображается (на ноуте исходящее отображается, не блочится, но передано 0 байт). Правила создавал, уже и вообще фаерволы на обеих сторонах вырубал, ничего не помогло. Брандмауер виндовс выключен.

WTF? Куда еще копать для дальнейшей диагностики?

Системы: на компе (где вебсервер) - вин7 х64, на ноуте - винХР сп3.

Comment: сокет не на 127.0.0.1:8889 висит?

Comment: @Etki, на нем висит, порт правильный

Comment: @kanaris, ну он и слушает подключения, приходящие на ip 127.0.0.1, который явно не соответствует ip реального сетевого интерфейса. Вешайте на 0.0.0.0 для подключения с любых интерфейсов, либо задавайте адрес того, что смотрит наружу.

Comment: Антивирус не стоит? Пусть слушает порт на ip сетевом 192.168.1.* ну или какой там у тебя в твоей сети. Просканируй telnet'on или nmap'om

Comment: @Etki, да, действительно, получилось. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев от [Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/etki)*

Скорее всего у вас сервер висит на 127.0.0.1:8889, т.е. локально к нему обратиться можно - он слушает подключения исходящие с локальной машины. Вешайте на 0.0.0.0 для подключения с любых интерфейсов, либо задавайте адрес того, что смотрит наружу.